# Show dropdown for Client Web Part property

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part

Is it possible to show a drop down list of values in a Client Web Part property (SharePoint hosted App for SPOnline)? I want to read values from somewhere else in site (say items from a list) and want to show those in drop down so that user can select one of them instead of having to type the value. Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible using the Client Web Part settings. You could though create your own settings interface in the Client web part itself

Comment: @RobertLindgren: Thanks. So what's the best practice for saving these settings and identifying them for the unique instance of the app part.

Comment: You can still save the setting as a client webpart property (as a string probably), or in a list or similar in the app itself

Comment: Please share any reference for saving the string as client webpart property.